# How to plot residuals against a regression line in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I have a dataset (found here- https://netfiles.umn.edu/users/nacht001/www/nachtsheim/Kutner/Appendix%20C%20Data%20Sets/APPENC01.txt) and I have done some R coding for linear regression. In the attached dataset the columns are not labelled. I had to label the columns of the dataset and save it as a csv and I apologize I can't get that on here… but the columns I am using are column 2 (`stay`) column 3(`age`) column 4(`infection`)  and column 12(`service`). I named the dataset `hospital`.

I am running a multiple linear regression to find the effects of age (`X1`), infection (`X2`), and service(`X3`) on stay (`Y`)

I am trying to plot the residuals against `Y` hat but I do not know if I am doing this correctly. I understand what a residual plot is, but I am unsure if I am supposed to add the `Y hat` regression line or if my code below is returning the proper plot. I also need to plot the residuals against the "two-factor interaction terms" which I am unsure how to do.

```
model.1<- data.frame(hospital$stay, hospital$age, hospital$infection, hospital$service)
fit.1<- lm(hospital$stay~ hospital$age + hospital$infection + hospital$service)
model.1.resid<- residuals(fit.1)
plot(fitted(fit.1), model.1.resid)
```

Comment: well that's why I am so confused, the question asks for me to "obtain the residuals and plot them against Y hat" is that just faulty wording for obtaining a residual plot and then adding the Y hat regression line to the plot?

Comment: Okay… also this might be strictly forbidden on this site so sorry if it is but would you be willing to like help me through this problem on a chat or something $$ I have a lot more questions

Comment: actually, plotting residuals against fitted values is a very common procedure.

Comment: okay well I don't even care if anyone wants to check a linear regression problem let me know I have all the coding and the work just want to see if I am doing it correctly and if my interpretation is correct.

Comment: Have a look at `library(car)` `qqPlot()` function which provides a more accurate method of assessing normality assumption than `plot()` does.

Answer (score 0):

You could give below a try.

```
library(car)
qqPlot(fit.1, labels=row.names(your_data_file), id.method="identify",
simulate=TRUE, main="Q-Q Plot")
# If you want to know more about qqPlot, please check ?qqPlot()
```